# Does $L^2$ - convergence imply convergence in probability?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, asymptotics

I am not very familiar with rigorous knowledge about convergence and asymptotic theory in statistics. Although my question is more statistics-related, my problem arises from the lack of knowledge about math regarding the difference between convergence in probability and $L^2$ convergence.

More precisely, if I have the following convergence:
$$||X(\hat{\beta}-\beta )||_2^2 =o_p(1)$$

where $X$ is a $n\times p$ matrix, $\beta,\hat{\beta}$ are $p\times 1$ respectively and $||y||_2^2 $ is defined as $\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i^2$. Hence, in that case, just a bracket squared (in that context the prediction error squared)

is this the same as saying $$X(\hat{\beta}-\beta)\rightarrow0$$ converges to zero in probability.

Comment: Never used it in case of convergence. Do you want to write an answer ?

Comment: What is $\|\cdot\|_2^2$ in this context? Are $X$ and $\beta$ vectors?

Comment: I think it follows from Chebyshev inequality. The converse is not valid.

Comment: I will edit my post a bit to give more information